# Does higher volatility of SDE imply lower probability of staying positive?

Tags: pr.probability, ap.analysis-of-pdes, probability-distributions, inequalities, stochastic-calculus

Given two SDEs $X^1$, $X^2$ :

$$X^i_t=1+t+\int_0^t\sigma_i(s)dW_s,\quad \forall t\ge 0,$$

where  $\sigma_i:\mathbb R_+\to [1/2,1]$ are non-decreasing s.t. $\sigma_1(t)\le \sigma_2(t)$ for all $t\ge 0$. Can we prove $\mathbb P[\inf_{0\le s\le t}X^1_s>0]\ge \mathbb P[\inf_{0\le s\le t}X^2_s>0]$ for all $t\ge 0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This follows by time change: The process $(X^i_t)$ equals the process $(1+t+W_{\tau_i(t)})$ in distribution, where
$$\tau_i(t):=\int_0^t\sigma_i(s)^2\,ds,$$
so that $\tau_2\ge\tau_1$ and hence for the corresponding inverse functions we have $\tau_2^{-1}\le\tau_1^{-1}$.

It follows that
$$\begin{aligned}
&\inf_{s\in[0,t]}(1+s+W_{\tau_2(s)}) \\ 
&=\inf_{u\in[0,\tau_2(t)]}(1+\tau_2^{-1}(u)+W_u) \\ 
&\le\inf_{u\in[0,\tau_1(t)]}(1+\tau_1^{-1}(u)+W_u) \\ 
&=\inf_{s\in[0,t]}(1+s+W_{\tau_1(s)}).
\end{aligned}$$

So, for all real $x$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
&P(\inf\limits_{s\in[0,t]}X^1_s>x) \\
&=P(\inf_{s\in[0,t]}(1+s+W_{\tau_1(s)})>x) \\ 
&\ge
P(\inf_{s\in[0,t]}(1+s+W_{\tau_2(s)})>x) \\ 
&=P(\inf\limits_{s\in[0,t]}X^2_s>x). 
\end{aligned}$$
Thus, the desired result follows.

Comment: Very nice observation! Thank you so much for the answer. Do you think this monotonicity can be helpful to derive the uniqueness of the solution at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410069/uniqueness-of-the-solution-to-some-sde?

Comment: @GJC20 : It may. Unfortunately, I am not an expert in SDE's, especially for non-Markov processes, and I don't have a good idea for that question. But I will have it in mind.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your consideration. Indeed, by defining the operator $\Gamma$ with $\Gamma[m](t):=\mathbb P[\inf_{0\le s\le t}Y^m_s>0]$, where $Y^{\alpha}_t:=X_0+t+\int_0^t dW_s/(1+m(s))$, one may construct an iterated sequence. More precisely, taking $m_0\equiv 1$ (resp. $m_0\equiv 1$) and setting $m_{n}:=\Gamma[m_{n-1}]$ for $n\ge 1$, we obtain a decreasing (resp. increasing) sequence lying between $0$ and $1$, so the limit must exist. In particular, we show the existence of the maximal solution $\overline m$ and the minimal solution $\underline m$.

Comment: If $\overline m=\underline m$,  the uniqueness follows

Comment: @GJC20 : Nice argument for the existence (a couple of typos there, though). I have been thinking about the linked uniqueness problem, having somewhat similar ideas. Will check if they hold and, if so, will write down an answer.

Comment: True. While it is too late to make modifications. The reasoning has appeared for a while, thanks to your proof, I am able to show the existence of the maximal and minimal solutions

Comment: @GJC20 : I have now posted a proof of the uniqueness, at https://mathoverflow.net/a/410768/36721.