# Continuation : Uniqueness of the solution to some SDE with discontinuous coefficient

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the SDE below

$$X_t=X_0+\int_0^t b(s)ds+\int_0^t\frac{dW_s}{1+m(s){\bf 1}_{\{b(s)>0\}}},\quad \forall t\ge 0,~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(\ast)$$

where $X_0>0$ is square integrable, $b:\mathbb R_+\to \mathbb R$ be bounded,  $m(t)=\mathbb P[\inf_{0\le s\le t}X_s>0]$ for all $t\ge 0$. Admitting that $(\ast)$ admits a solution, can we prove the solution is unique (assuming $b$ is as nice as possible)?

PS :

1. More precisely, with $\tau:=\inf\{t\ge 0: X_t\le 0\}$, I pursue the uniqueness of the stopped process $(X_{\tau\wedge t})_{t\ge 0}$;
2. Iosif has proved in [Uniqueness of the solution to some SDE](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410069/uniqueness-of-the-solution-to-some-sde) the uniqueness (see also the post for the existence) when $b>0$ and I wish to find a counter-example if the uniqueness doesn't hold.